# Flexbox height percentages

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a basic flexbox layout that I am trying to apply height percentages to, currently they all occupy the same percentage…

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.row_one {
  background: blue;
  height: 30%;
}

.row_two {
  background: wheat;
  height: 30%;
}

.row_three {
  background: yellow;
  height: 40%;
}

.fill-height-or-more {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fill-height-or-more > div {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="some-area fill-height-or-more">
  <div class="row_one">
    Row 1
  </div>
  <div class="row_two">
    Row 2
  </div>
  <div class="row_three">
    Row 3
  </div>
</section>
```

Is this even possible with flexbox? If so, does anybody have an example they can point me in the direction of?

Comment: The problem is that the <section> element doesn't have a defined height (min-height doesn't count). So there's a missing link and percentage heights on the rows fall back to content height.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `flex` property instead of percentages.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.row_one {
  background: blue;
  flex: 3
}

.row_two {
  background: wheat;
  flex: 3;
}

.row_three {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 4;
}

.fill-height-or-more {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fill-height-or-more > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="some-area fill-height-or-more">
  <div class="row_one">
    Row 1
  </div>
  <div class="row_two">
    Row 2
  </div>
  <div class="row_three">
    Row 3
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @fightstarr20 No problem! I try and avoid using height percentages and height in general when it comes to flexbox. It often breaks in Safari and IE, if there is a way of defining the size with flex: property, it's always better than % ;)

Comment: How can I stop the text from affecting the heights?

Comment: @fightstarr20 Try adding this class: .elementNotAffectingText {flex-basis: 0; overflow: auto}